# Camera callback not firing on cordova 3.x.x

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, callback, camera

```
function getpicture(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFailPic,
           { destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
             sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
             saveToPhotoAlbum: true });
    return false;
}
```

Im using this code, provided by the Cordova API, to get a picture from the camera and then save the URI in the database.

I just created a project, new and clean, using Cordova CLI and Cordova 3.5.0.

The weird part is that this doesn't happen everytime. Sometimes I get the picture, the callback fires, all good. But when it doesn't work it goes like this:

- I take the picture, hit save 
  (callback should fire here)
- It goes back to the index of my app
- I take picture again, it fires the callback processing the first picture

My plugin version: "org.apache.cordova.camera": "0.2.8"

Comment: have you tried removing `return false;`?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I did, still not firing from time to time. I can't get the reason this happens, it doesn't give any errors, just nothing happens.

Comment: are you waiting for the `deviceready` event to fire before trying this?

Comment: @Rafael Have you solved the problem? The same happens to me as well.

Comment: @PetrB Not really, I read that they will be fixing it on the 3.5.1 but nothing so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to comment that I'm getting the same thing with this block and org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.3-dev.

```
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onCaptureSuccess, onCaptureFail, {
                quality: 60,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                targetWidth: 500,
                targetHeight: 500
            });
```

The crazy thing is that it only happens when the targetWidth and targetHeight are set. Otherwise, it works just fine.